# Sql view very slow executing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this sql view

```
SELECT     
    dbo.CustomFilterDetails.CustomFilterID, 
    dbo.ItemCustomParameters.CustomFilterDetailsID, 
    dbo.Item.ItemID
FROM         
    dbo.ItemCustomParameters 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CustomFilterDetails ON dbo.ItemCustomParameters.CustomFilterDetailsID = dbo.CustomFilterDetails.CustomFilterDetailsID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Item ON dbo.Item.ItemName LIKE dbo.ItemCustomParameters.Value 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.ItemParameter ON dbo.ItemParameter.ItemID IS NULL 
                      OR dbo.ItemParameter.Value LIKE dbo.ItemCustomParameters.Value 
                      OR dbo.ItemParameter.Name LIKE dbo.ItemCustomParameters.Name
```

Why it is so slow working?

Comment: Likes and ORs, perhaps. Or lack of indexes.

Comment: Try replacing the JOIN clauses with WHERE clauses. It should be faster..

Comment: Wee need a lot more information to answer this. Tables definition, indexes, execution plan, etc

Comment: I tryied to do so, it's the same effect, when i write = instead like it takes only 30 s

Comment: Also, why do you keep doing `ColumnA LIKE ColumnB`?, that is the same as `ColumnA = ColumnB`...and how much time is "slow working"?

Comment: if I remove group by it works faster also

Comment: do u have any indexes created?

Comment: I need to search phrases from B column with %ColumnA%

Comment: I don't have indexes, how to use it in view?

Comment: @Ignas - Then the join condition should be `ColumnA LIKE '%'+ColumnB + '%'` otherwise its just an `ColumnA = ColumnB`. Oh, and this **will** make it slower

Comment: create non clustered indexes on your tables on the columns that you are using in the view

Comment: http://okayguru.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/create-non-clustered-index.html

Comment: You need not call indexes from view. Indexes are used to sort the data in the tables and store it that will be readily available. This helps a lot in improving the performance. Just create the indexes and run this view and see if it makes difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the **LIKE**  clauses in this query. **LIKE** is used for pattern matching, and unless you have full text indexes defined on all of the columns you're comparing, any indexes created against those columns will not be used. You should use "=" instead, and make sure that the following indexes exist:

```
Item.ItemName
ItemParameter.Value
ItemParameter.Name
ItemCustomParameters.Value
ItemCustomParameters.Name
```

I'm assuming you already have indexes on

```
ItemCustomParameters.CustomFilterDetailsID
CustomFilterDetails.CustomFilterDetailsID
```

I assume that you're **LIKE** to including matches that have different cases in their values? If this is not the case, then replacing LIKE with = will already have fixed your problem. Otherwise, use a case-insensitive collation for the relevant fields. Then you can compare strings with varying cases using =, without losing the benefit of your indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE Item ALTER COLUMN ItemName NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS
ALTER TABLE ItemParameter ALTER COLUMN Name NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS
ALTER TABLE ItemParameter ALTER COLUMN Value NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS
```

... Etc.

Then replace the LIKEs with = as described above and create your indexes, and it should work fine, although still not ideal. If you're still suffering performance issues after this, consider linking the Item, ItemParameter and ItemCustomParaeter tables using integer keys. Not knowing your database structure, I can't give you much more information on that, but effectively it means that the task of matching items to parameters is done at the time that the parameters are created or assigned, and not every time the view is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need not call indexes from view. Indexes are used to sort the data in the tables and store it that will be readily available. This helps a lot in improving the performance. Just create the indexes and run this view and see if it makes difference